# rabbitmq - consumer without channel

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

There is clustered rabbitmq.
There is one connected consumer to it.

```
root@serwer1:~# rabbitmqctl list_consumers -p vhost1
Listing consumers ...
queue1.dlq  <rabbit@serwer1.3.9529.109> amq.ctag-C5lFDLY7LZjnDdi1hjbAIA true    1000    []
...done.
```

There is connected with it channel:

```
root@serwer1:~# rabbitmqctl list_channels vhost pid state connection  |grep rabbit@serwer1.3.9529.109
vhost1  <rabbit@serwer1.3.9529.109> running <rabbit@serwer1.3.9537.109>
```

But - there is no connected connection for it:

```
root@serwer1:~# rabbitmqctl list_connections vhost pid state  |grep rabbit@serwer1.3.9529.109
root@serwer1:~#
```

How such situation is possible? How to fix it?
(rabbitmq 3.3.5 from debian jessie)

Comment: does `rabbitmqctl list_connections` (without grep filter) return anything at all? Basically, channel exists only inside the connection, so it should be there.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the logs. A channel cannot exist without a connection underlying it, and a consumer resides on a channel. Either you think you have a consumer and do not, or you're missing something.

Comment: yes, there any other (correct) consumers connected with connections. I was sure that consumer need to be connected with connection, but here i have an example where it's not corelated. And i don't know if it's bug within my (really ancient - 3.3.5 is a bit old) rmq cluster, or there is any scenario where such situation is possible.On the other hand - what do with it? Restart rabbitmqs can help? It's production system and i dont want to lost messages on that rabbit.